# Launch java server vm by default

Tags: java, jvm

I have both Client VM and Server VM on my machine.

$ java -client -version
Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM

$ java -server -version
Java HotSpot(TM) Server VM

By default Client VM is used:
$ java -version
Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM

I'm trying to launch some java applications (like glassfish, teamcity, upsource etc.), by none of these launches, because they can't open listening connection, because they are being launched by Client VM, so I think I need to set java Server VM by default.

Does anybody knows how to do that?

Comment: If you install the 64-bit JVM it will always use the server JVM.  I suggest you use 64-bit for the server services.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don’t know what kind of launcher you have used, but it is very unlikely that these applications ran on a client JVM as their launchers usually select a server JVM by default.

However, you have been misguided by the names as these JVM types have nothing to do with the question of whether the application can opening listening connections. These two JVM shapes just alter the behavior regarding performance. Simply said, a server JVM is optimized for long running applications, but this difference is about to vanish in future JVMs anyway, so then you will never have to worry about “server” vs. “client” JVMs anymore.

So if your application can’t opening a port for listening, the possible reasons are

- The operating system does not allow it (e.g. certain ports might require administrator privileges)
- The `SecurityManager` of the JRE does not allow it (due to its policy)
- The port is already in use

But it’s not because your JVM is a so-called “client” JVM.

Answer (score 0):

The decision it based on your hardware and operating system. For an overview have a look here:
[Server-Class Machine Detection](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/vm/server-class.html)

Comment: I have Client and Server both. Can I force system to use always Server VM?

Comment: If you have a 64bit system: yes, as @Peter wrote "install the 64 bit JVM". If you have a system with "default to client vm" or "is not decided as server class": no